# nowrap on table header with float elements?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table contained in a scrollable div and want the column headers to not wrap. Problem comes from float elements in the TH tag.  I want the SPAN in the header to float to the right but it breaks to a new line. I've tried wrapping the text and the spans in a div but that didn't help. Ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/e0wn7986/2/

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: gray
}

table thead tr th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table thead tr th span {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>


  <div class="wrapper">


    <table width="100%" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Some Column</th>
          <th>

            This is another <span>&uarr;</span><span>&darr;</span></th>
          <th>One more time<span>&uarr;</span><span>&darr;</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>testing some long stuff</td>
          <td>foobar moobar wizzle wuzzle</td>
          <td style="white-space:nowrap">lets go on and on and on...lets go on and on and on...</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use label than span :  `<label>&uarr;</label><label>&darr;</label>`

```
.wrapper{width:400px;overflow:auto;background:gray}
table thead tr th{white-space: nowrap;}
table thead tr th label{float:right}
```

Comment: Made no difference for me